# How to use python timeit to get median runtime

Tags: python, python-3.x, benchmarking, microbenchmark, timeit

I want to benchmark a bit of python code (not the language I am used to, but I have to do some comparisons in python). I have understood that `timeit` is a good tool for this, and I have a code like this:

```py
n = 10
duration = timeit.Timer(my_func).timeit(number=n)
duration/n
```

to measure the mean runtime of the function. Now, I want to instead have the median time (the reason is that I want to make a comparison to something I get in median time, and it would be good to use the same measure in all cases). Now, `timeit` only seems to return the full runtime, and not the time of each individual run, so I am not sure how to find the median runtime. What is the best way to get this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat) method instead, which gives you the individual times as a list:

```
import timeit
from statistics import median

def my_func():
    for _ in range(1000000):
        pass

n = 10
durations = timeit.Timer(my_func).repeat(repeat=n, number=1)
print(median(durations))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY4xCsMwDEV3nUKjDSXEdCmF3KJ7cBO71WDZyMqQ07tuE/qWj/jwvsqu78zXW5HWKJUsikopkEKUnLCqV6pKS8WzTWElzwBriJj2OW68GHsH7MQsOCMxiudXMG78cZZfiq8VgHFCN8K6SXdnrv08JodHDzGn1Q4SSvBqjpj4grylZ5DJWShCrOb4xfxN1kJrHw)

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks a lot!